# Conflict between jQuery and JavaScript single script

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

im using multiple JS scripts allong with jquery in a single html page. These scripts include a slider, a sticky menu, shadowbox and finally, a image preview script. **This image-preview script is the one that makes the other ones to fail, and it works alone.** Its a simple peace of code inserted after the body tags.

Here's the code for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery.noConflict();
(function(jQuery){  

jQuery('#first a').imgPreview();

})(jQuery);
//]]>
</script>
```

Full HEAD code:

```
<script src="js/jsapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#slider").easySlider({
            auto: true, 
            continuous: true
        });
    }); 
</script>

<script src="js/scroll.inicio.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nav.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#sticky').onePageNav({
changeHash: true
  });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top)
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick')
  else
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
  }
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
  });
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}
function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-        2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src;         x.src=a[i+2];}
    }
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shadowbox.js"></script>

<script src="js/imgpreview.full.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">Shadowbox.init({ overlayOpacity: 0.9 });</script>
```

**Console shows this 3 errors**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined imgpreview.full.jquery.js:58
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function index.html:21
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function index.html:49
```

I need to locate where the conflict is and how to fix it.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have error in console (F12)?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined imgpreview.full.jquery.js:58
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function index.html:21
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function index.html:49

Comment: First of all, have a look on line 58 of the file imgpreview.full.jquery.js, you have a critical error. It is possible that the rest of the JS code is not executed after that.

Comment: You use `jQuery.noConflict()`, yet later use $ in what appears to be jQuery code (after it has been released) so that will likely fail.

Answer (score 0):

This will fail:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// script after this fails
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#slider").easySlider({
        auto: true, 
        continuous: true
    });
});
```

properly used:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// script after this fails
(function($){   
    $("#slider").easySlider({
        auto: true, 
        continuous: true
    });
})(jQuery);
```

one proper use might also be:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){  
     $('#first a').imgPreview();
})(jQuery);
//other library code here...
```

Comment: that didn' work for me. The code from the imgPreview script causes the other ones to fail. Without it, they all work fine. Tryed to use the one you put but didnt work

Comment: Let me guess, you are using 1.9+ version of jQuery - so you will need to update that plugin if you plan to use it.